# How to share common id for two channels in a call

Tags: java, freeswitch

I am working on communication between two applications in freeswitch, I have done following from a java program,

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( "/bin/bash", "-c", "cd /usr/local/freeswitch/bin && ./fs_cli -x \"originate loopback/1234/default &bridge(sofia/internal/1789)\"" );
processBuilder.start();
```

It's working fine, I just want to run the same program for more no of times to test the system capability, so If I need to run it more no of times I just want to share a common id between to communicating channels in a call, Please suggest some method where we can share common variable, Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Have a class implement runnable

```
class myRunnable implements Runnable
{

    int commonId = 1234; // all threads have this same common id
    public void run()
    {

         // do something with the common id

         // all threads share this common code
         ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( "/bin/bash", "-c", "cd /usr/local/freeswitch/bin && ./fs_cli -x \"originate loopback/1234/default &bridge(sofia/internal/1789)\"" );
         processBuilder.start();
    }
}
```

Create and start a thread

```
int i=0,n=5;
for(i=0;i<n;i++) new Thread(new myRunnable).start(); // this will fire off 5 threads
```

Thus you'd have 5 different process with the same common id.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am sorry it's purely freeswitch-java related problem, so I need a ESL client method to share common variable or id between two channels in a call not id's for processes